# How to implement camel-kafka manual commit?

Tags: apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

Has anyone worked on Kafka manual commit using Apache camel, we are not finding any clue to implement it, We are trying to do so using camel router as :

```
 from("kafka:{{kafka.hostname}}:{{kafka.port}}?topic={{kafka.topic}}&groupId={{kafka.consumer.groupid}}&autoOffsetReset=none&autoCommitEnable=false&maxPollRecords=3").process(new Processor() { 
 @Override 
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {.....}).end();
```

Kindly help us out in the issue,
Thanks.

Comment: is anyone have an answer for this?

Comment: This question should be considered a duplicate of this question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843677/how-to-transactionally-poll-kafka-from-camel/52300250#52300250

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transactionally poll Kafka from Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843677/how-to-transactionally-poll-kafka-from-camel)